# Phalcon - get encrypted cookie value

Tags: php, cookies, phalcon

I try to set and get cookie in Phalcon. I have registered cookie in DI 
like here http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/cookies.html

```
$di->set('cookies', function() {
    $cookies = new Phalcon\Http\Response\Cookies();
    $cookies->useEncryption(true);
    return $cookies;
});

$di->set('crypt', function() {
    $crypt = new Phalcon\Crypt();
    $crypt->setKey('#_+//*(*&eA|;76$');
    return $crypt;
});
```

In Controller I set cookie like this:

```
$this->cookies->set('test', 'test', time()+600);
```

After that I want to get cookie:

```
$val = $this->cookies->get('test');
```

First strangу thing - is the if I try to print my `$val` I get not value of this variable but strange Object (`Phalcon\Http\Cookie Object`).
Second strange - if I use encryption the next construction returns `false` for me.

```
if ($val == 'test'){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

If I dont use encryption counstruction above returns `true` But if I try to print `$val` which setted without encryption I get not value but same strange object.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. `$this->cookies->get('test')` returns you a [cookie object](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Cookie.html) that's also described in the [documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Response_Cookies.html). You should be getting your value like this:

```
$this->cookies->get('test')->getValue();
```

So, you can set anything you want, but when you retrieve it, it returns `Phalcon\Http\Cookie` with quite a few methods. Inconsistent, but apparently supposed to make your life easier.

Comment: sometimes after decryption $this->cookies->get('test')->getValue(); returns value with extra white-spaces around it. Use trim:

$val = trim($this->cookies->get('test')->getValue());